# Sonatype Nexus Consuming Large Amount of Memory

Tags: nexus, sonatype

Hoping someone with a bit more knowledge of java than I have can shed some light here.

I have a Sonatype Nexus setup which I have inherited and it is consuming a large amount of memory in a very short amount of time. In fact after restarting the service, used memory went from 963MB to 6448MB in less than 4 hours! (there is 8GB physical memory allocated to this machine)

The wrapper.conf file has been set to use between 256MB to 2000MB

Here is a snippet of the configuration file:

```
# Additional JVM parameters (tune if needed, but match the sequence of numbers!)
wrapper.java.additional.1=-XX:MaxPermSize=192m
wrapper.java.additional.2=-Djava.io.tmpdir=./tmp
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.protocol="plain ssl"
wrapper.java.additional.4.stripquotes=TRUE
#wrapper.java.additional.5=-Xdebug
#wrapper.java.additional.6=-Xnoagent
#wrapper.java.additional.7=-Djava.compiler=NONE
#wrapper.java.additional.8=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000
#wrapper.java.additional.9=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

wrapper.app.parameter.1=./conf/jetty.xml
wrapper.app.parameter.2=./conf/jetty-requestlog.xml

# Size Java memory, in MB (-Xms)
wrapper.java.initmemory=256
# Size Java memory, in MB (-Xmx). This option only supports a setting up to 4000 (4Gb).
# If you need more, comment this option out and use an explicit wrapper.java.additional option with -Xmx
wrapper.java.maxmemory=2000
```

I have also attached a screen shot of the top command showing the java threads.

If you need to see the full configuration file or any other information, let me know.

Thanking you in advanced,

Doug.

Some additional Info:

Using version 2.11.3-01
Roughly 252 artifacts

Comment: How many artifacts do you have there?

Comment: There was a bug in versions 2.4 and 2.5 of Nexus which could cause this.  We switched the lucene index implementation to use memory mapped files, and it turned out this could cause large amounts of virtual memory to be consumed due to a VM bug.  If you're on an older version of Nexus try upgrading.

Comment: Hello JBaruch. We have about 252 artifacts (used this command to confirm "find /opt/nexus-2.11.3-01 -name *.jar | wc -l" )

Hello rseddon, we are using the following version "nexus-2.11.3-01". You mentioned something about using using memory mapped files which was consuming high memory. Is this a setting we can change? This isn't a heavily utilized system